# Is there a command in Fortran77 or later that decompresses a file?

Tags: fortran77, compression

I have a file that is compressed and I want to decompress it.
Do you know if there is a command or do I need to follow another path?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one built into FORTRAN 77, but you can shell out to the UNIX commands 
gzip, gunzip to compress/decompress a file (assuming you are running on UNIX).

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://home.wanadoo.nl/~johndon/index.html) help you?